# Autoload Magento 2 Issue

Tags: magento2, composer, php-7

My website has been migrated to a new server in the same hosting for reasons of optimization, after it, appear this issue when I'm trying to enter in any page of Magento

> Autoload error
>
> Passed array does not specify an existing static method (class
>   'Facebook_Autoload' not found)

I cannot use any command of Magento at the ssh console for the same reason, everywhere shows that issue

The only command related to Magento that I can use is a composer

How can I solve this being that specification the only info that shows me (Without any extension or any line of code)?

My PHP Version is 7.3

(Before migration everything works okay)

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are missing some library files. Try executing `composer install` command.

Comment: Still have same problem after composer install, is there a way to see where is that library?